# Issue with redux offline config

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-offline

I am using redux offline, and it is working correctly. But the problem is that when I make an API request offline and then come online in a few minutes, the API gets called, but if I don't come online for several hours, it doesn't call.
My config is ---

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {offline} from '@redux-offline/redux-offline';
import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const customConfig = {
  ...offlineConfig,
  retry: neverRetry,
};

function neverRetry(action, attemptNumber) {
  return 1000 * Math.pow(2, attemptNumber)
}
 
export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), offline(customConfig)),
);
```

Please help me with my offline configureation also I am sending images and videos with offline api so is there a problem of storage too??